# I get an undefined offset after passing the requests into the function

Tags: laravel, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get the time taken to reach a distance using google distantmatrix.I get this error after passing the the required arguments into the function.

```
Public function GetDrivingDistance($lat1, $lat2, $long1, $long2) {

  $data1 = setting::where('id',1)->first();

  $key = $data1->key;

  $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".$lat1.",".$long1."&destinations=".$lat2.",".$long2."&mode=driving&language=pl-PL"."&key=".$key;

  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

  $response = curl_exec($ch);

  curl_close($ch);

  $response_a = json_decode($response, true);

  $dist = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];

  $time = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'];

  return array('distance' => $dist, 'time' => $time);
}
```

Error:

```
undefined offset: 0
```

At $dist = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];

Comment: Can you show us what's in `$response_a`?

Comment: What is origin and destination coordinates? Probably Google just returns NOT_FOUND and you don't have `rows` elements in the response. Did you check the status of the response?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `data_get` helper function like this:

```php
$dist = data_get($response_a, 'rows.0.elements.0.distance.text');

$time = data_get($response_a, 'rows.0.elements.0.duration.text');
```

Using `data_get` method, `null` will be returned if the specified key is not found instead of getting an error.

See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-data-get) for more info.